# Add Shared Mountpoint storage in Cloudstack?

Tags: cloudstack

I'm trying to use a SAN storage as Primary Storage for my Cloudstack KVM Cluster in the Basic Installation. [Cloudstack's document](http://cloudstack-administration.readthedocs.org/en/latest/storage.html#hypervisor-support-for-primary-storage) says that, in order to use Fiber Channel for my SAN storage, I have to use **Shared Mountpoint** storage.

However, I can't select the **Shared Mountpoint** option in the Basic Installation - the only option available is **NFS**.

[Screenshot of Add Primary Storage section in Cloudstack Basic Installation showing 'NFS' as the only option for Primary Storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnDEj.png)

How can I add **Shared Mountpoint** storage as my Primary Storage?

- **CloudStack:** 4.5.2
- **OS:** CentOS 6.7

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to mount the SAN storage as "NFS mount" on "KVM host".

Check if you can discover the san storage on KVM host:
iscsiadm --mode discovery --type sendtargets--portal

Then list it by:

```
fdisk -l
```

And mount it on any directory:

```
mkdir /mnt/sanstorage
mount /dev/sdd1 /mnt/sanstorage
```

(also add it in fstab)

Now add the storage as NFS on cloudstack primary storage, same as the screenshot you shared.
Server will be your KVM host ip and path will be mountpoint i.e /mnt/sanstorage